# Error saying the viewController does not exist.iOS Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, viewcontroller

In my app,
It is showing some error like :

```
 "unknown type name 'purchasedViewController'; DId you mean 'UIPageViewController'?
```

But actually there is a VC named `purchasedViewController` and i have imported it in the current VC.

But when i create an object of `purchasedViewController` in the current VC like:

```
@property(strong, nonatomic) purchasedViewController *purchasedController;
```

im getting an error message saying :

```
"unknown type name 'purchasedViewController'; DId you mean 'UIPageViewController'?
```

Why is it happening?Any idea?

**************EDIT**************
This is my ".h" file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <StoreKit/StoreKit.h>
#import "PurchasedViewController.h"

@interface MainScreenViewController : UIViewController
- (IBAction)purchaseItemAction:(id)sender;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *Label;

@property(strong,nonatomic) PurchasedViewController *purchaseController;

-(void)Purchased;

@end
```

Comment: Is this property declaration in the .m or the .h and where have you imported the file. Please show all of this code. Also naming convention is to start class names with an uppercase

Comment: Would it be possible to share the header of your custom controller and the import statement?

Comment: Please have a look at the edited question.

Comment: make sure "PurchasedViewController" has target marked for your app name

Comment: just set `@class purchasedViewController;`  above `@interface`

Comment: Can you post your PurchasedViewController.h file?

Comment: i have added @class purchasedViewController; above interface,,,it worked..thank you all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to give Forward declaration like

```
  @class purchasedViewController;
  @interface MainScreenViewController : UIViewController


  @end
```

I think it works for you

Comment: It should already been imported using #import "PurchasedViewController.h"

Comment: Thank you bhavin,It really worked.But Y is it happening like this?

Comment: This tells the compiler that there exists a class called "PurchasedViewController." When there are circular dependencies, like when two classes have instances of each other, using forward declarations of the classes resolves the confusion that results.

Answer (score 1):

You might have a problem if somehow headers are importing each other. To avoid that, change the import in your header to look like this:

```
//MainScreenViewController.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <StoreKit/StoreKit.h>
@class PurchasedViewController;

@interface MainScreenViewController : UIViewController
...
```

This will tell the header that the class exist but not actually importing it.

Then, in the implementation (`.m`) file of `MainScreenViewController` you can actually call the import:

```
//MainScreenViewController.m

#import "PurchasedViewController.h"
...
```